# Comparing Strings in Swift 3 gives false results (Linux)

Tags: swift, ascii, string-comparison

I don't understand the way Swift compares strings.

Swift (3.0.2) on Linux:

```
print("2" < "=") //returns false
```

but other languages such as Ruby:

```
p("2:" < "=:") #returns true
```

It seems we should have swift returning true since "2" comes before "=" in ASCII order. Is it a bug or do I miss something?

Comment: print("2" < "=") prints true for me

Comment: Both `print("2" < "=")` and  `print("2:" < "=:")` print "true" in Swift.

Comment: is it about `print` vs `p` return value?

Comment: `print("2" < "=")` actually prints `false` on **Linux.** – Unfortunately, the author did not mention this important detail in the question (only in the comments to an answer).

Comment: How should I have known that it was only a Linux-Swift-bug?

Comment: I could reproduce the problem on Ubuntu. Voting to reopen the question.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments, it seems that you are testing this on Linux only. There is an open bug how Swift handles char ordering on Linux, see [SR-530](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-530)

---

Original answer:

Ruby's `p` returns object passed as its argument.

Equivalent comparison would be Ruby `puts` vs Swift `print`. Both return (almost) nothing.

Comment: In swift one has: `let a = "2:" < "=:"; print(a) -> false`. In ruby ` a = "2:" < "=:"; puts(a) -> true`. I don't understand why swift gives false since in ASCII order "2" comes before "=". Do I miss something in the comparison? I get the same weird result in <https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl> and <https://iswift.org/playground>. I have no other way to try. I am learning Swift.

Comment: @user3166747: That seems to be a Linux-specific problem (which explains why nobody could reproduce it). You should add to your question that you are testing that in the IBM Swift sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If it is a bug it is quite annoying! Thanks to the generous downvoters too:-(